# IE 9, 10, 11 Failing to Render Content of One Particular DIV (Added Using JS)

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I am having a strange problem with IE 11 and IE 10 (and IE 10 and IE 9 using IE 11's compatibility rendering) whereby one particular `div` is not being rendered until and unless I open the developer tools and click on any tag in the DOM explorer. Once I do that the `div` contents are immediately rendered.

The page in question renders correctly on all versions of Chrome, Firefox and on IE 5, <strike>6</strike>, 7 and 8. [EDIT: IE6 not tested; and 5, 7 and 8 tested via IE 11's document rendering emulation modes].

The page is authenticated and part of a complex SPA client with the majority of the HTML generated using JS, and what is delivered from the server is a bare outline where the sidebar content (which contains the non-rendered `div`) is simply:

```
<div id="Top" onclick="RpA.reload()" title="..." style="visibility: hidden; cursor: pointer;">
    <img src="images/blank.gif"/>
</div>

<div id="LibraryList">
</div>

<div id="LogoutWrapper">
    <input class="LogoutButton" type="button" value="Log out" onclick="RpA.logout();"/>
</div>
```

and it's the first `div` block within the "LibraryList" which is not rendered, though the following (quite complex) table is. After JS manipulation the content of "LibraryList" is:

```
<div id="LibraryList" data-RpA_ListName="Library"> 
    <div id="MultiSetup"> 
        <div class="DefaultSetup" id="MultiSetup_ImageWrap">
            <img src="/.../kingkong6.gif">
        </div>
        <div id="MultiSetup_Text">
            <a href="javascript:RpA.MultiSetup.edit_selBlock_start();">switch setup</a>
            <b>Default Setup</b>
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>

    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        ...
    </table>
</div>
```

While the JS is too complex in it's entirety to post here, it boils down to resolving the details via AJAX, finding the container `div` element and then injecting the resolved template using:

```
ele.innerHTML=Tpl.get("MultiSetup_Wrap").toString(stpobj,addobj);
```

Since the block renders immediately I try to examine the DOM, I can't be totally certain, but everything about the HTML and CSS is exactly as I expect and I can find no reason there why the block is not displayed.

So far I seem to have eliminated timing and sequencing, that is, it doesn't seem to matter where in the long sequence of page content generation I put this particular `div` snippet, nor does it seem to be affected by client or server hardware speed.

Any suggestions or advice on how to proceed from here?

**Update 1:** If I do a deferred `show()` on the element using jQuery, it does display after the timeout (of any length - I've tried 1, 100, 500 and 1000 ms); for example:

```
setTimeout(function(){$("#MultiSetup").show()},1000);
```

**Update 2:** OK, so I have pinned this down to the fact that the enclosing `div` has CSS `display:none;` set in IE 9+, but not in Chrome, Firefox or IE 8-. And as soon as I click on an element in the DOM tree it's magically changed to `display:block`. Looking like an out and out bug in IE to me.

Comment: What code are you using to place the div on the page?  I also notice a small typo `<img src="/.../kingkong6.gif">`.  One too many dots in your src attribute. It shouldn't cause problems putting the div on the page, though.

Comment: @Robbert: That's not a typo it's an ellipsis, I just eliminated part of the path to avoid leaking company info.

Comment: The code to add the HTML is a wildly complex series of AJAX calls achieved by means of multiple JS objects, using inheritance. (I realize that's not very helpful, but I truly can't conceive of any way to boil it down in any way that would be useful to post here; there would still be hundreds of lines of JS). However, I've added the final JS call, which just sets the innerHTML.

Comment: Is the javascript console showing any errors in IE?  What if you were to output the innerHTML of your div after it has been appended, i.e. `alert(ele.innerHTML)`. Does this show anything?

Comment: Can u post a simplified example @ jsfiddle? E.g. instead of actual AJAX call use result string you get

Comment: @Robbert: No, there are no console errors reported. I have console logged the resolved template HTML string immediately before and after setting it and it's complete and correct.

Comment: Seems to work by itself: http://jsfiddle.net/Su5cv/2/

Comment: Using the developer tools, I can execute a jQuery query on the invisible element and it remains invisible. I am using that now to see if anything is amiss in the DOM definition. So far all content is correct and nothing is flagged as hidden.

Comment: Instead of assigning `innerHTML` can u try jQuery's `$(htmlCode).appendTo('#MultiSetup_Text')` ?

Comment: Why are you bothering with any IE before IE8? IE5 usage is non-existant, IE7 is less than 2% and IE6 is only used in China.

Comment: @Mgetz I beleive OP mentioned IE9+

Comment: @YuriyGalanter "The page in question renders correctly on all versions of Chrome, Firefox and on IE 5, 6, 7 and 8." The reason I brought it up is in most cases like this, old hack code for older versions of IE breaks the newer ones which don't need it.

Comment: @Mgetz Ah sorry must've blocked it out :) I believe those aren't real-life scenarios, but rather modes supported by IE emulation

Comment: @YuriyGalanter nope IE 11 only supports Quirks, and 7+ hence the confusion about why IE6 would be included in there. Also I would assume that if a page is working right in quirks mode something else is missing... like a `<!doctype html>`

Comment: @Mgetz: Nope, IE11 lets you emulate all versions back to IE5 via the developer tools. However, I have narrowed things down now to the display CSS attribute being "none", but only in IE 9+. I am working on figuring out why that is now. (Oh, wait - I didn't notice that IE6 is not included in the emulation modes; sorry)

Comment: @Mgetz: Oh, perhaps "quirks" is what MS mean by emulating IE 5??

Comment: @SoftwareMonkey aye IE5 is "Quirks Mode" and should be avoided on the modern internet. Also [`display:none;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) hides that content.

Comment: @Mgetz: See my answer; this is a fault in the IE 9+ application of the `:empty` selector.

Comment: Just by the way, we don't officially support anything earlier than IE 8, but it was salient, I thought, that the change in behavior is demonstrably introduced when using IE 9.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This turns out to be a result of having the CSS selector:

```
#MultiSetup:empty { display: none; }
```

Apparently, IE 9+ continues to apply the `:empty` selector properties when the element ceases to be empty, so it remains hidden. When an element in the DOM tree is clicked it must cause some internal revalidation which then ceases to apply the properties.

Removing this selector resolves the problem (as does executing an explicit change when the innerHTML is set).

Comment: Just ran into a really similar issue and your post saved my day. In my situation we are rendering a number of react components on the page, and one of the components would not load until the developer tools were opened and the page was refreshed. 

Rendering nothing instead of an empty div solved the problem.